# datepicker not appearing when text field is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Following the link:

```
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_introduction.ashx
```

& then:

```
http://jquery.com/download/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DDownloading_jQuery%26redirect%3Dno
```

I have included the script files at the top of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then I have included the code for the datepicker:

```
<input type="text" id="simple-date" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// the jQuery ready shortcut  
$(function () {  
    // set up our datepicker  
    $("#simple-date").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

but nothing happens when I click the text field....shouldnt a datepicker load?
Please advise.....thanks

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Just to be sure, is your field id `#simple-date`?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin on your document

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And have a look on themes too  on the official site,I linked

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKhZg/517/)

Comment: It says ur src link was not found. i've used the other link someone provided but still nothing happens, thanks for reply

Comment: You've to add the protocol to the URL. This is a relative URL without a scheme: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: @John Added one demo fiddle ..Hope that helps

Comment: cant understand it....it works fine in the fiddle (thanks btw) but does not work for me....what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the jquery ui inclusion.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add both the CSS:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

and the JS for `jQuery UI`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where did you include `jQuery UI`?